# Any good Java Swing Timeline Widget?

Tags: java, swing, widget, timeline

Is anybody aware of a good  Java Swing Timeline Widget with features comparable to the Janus Winforms timeline component?

Answer (score 10):

Finally I found a Java timeline widget which fulfills my requirements:

[Jaret timebars component](http://jaret.de/timebars/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

A pretty good component which comes close is the FlexGantt available at http://www.dlsc.com

I will give it a try

Comment: I just noted the licensing options and the price.

This is way to expensive and too unflexible and no option for me...